How do non-LDS Christians defend using the same explanations that LDS do for Jesus's 'this generation' prophecy?
LDS Prophecy
Joseph Smith made the following prophecy predicting a temple to be built in Independence, Missouri:
Doctrines and Covenants 84:5:

For verily this generation shall not all pass away until an house shall be built unto the Lord, and a cloud shall rest upon it, which cloud shall be even the glory of the Lord, which shall fill the house.

No LDS temple was ever constructed in Independence, and Mormons were driven out of the state. Non-LDS Christians point to this prophecy as a clear example of Joseph Smith failing the Deuteronomic test of a prophet. On the other hand, LDS Christians offer numerous explanations for this apparent discrepancy:

The prophecy was conditional, and was delayed because the Mormons were not faithful
"This generation" does not refer to a generation of people but to an age or dispensation
"This generation" does not refer to the generation of Joseph Smith's contemporaries, but to a later group
The prophecy did actually come true in the 19th century, because the "house" in 84:5 referred to the temple built in Kirtland, OH four years after the prophecy

Gospel Prophecy
The gospel of Matthew records another disputed prophecy:
Matthew 24:29-34:

29 Immediately after the suffering of those days the sun will be darkened, and the moon will not give its light; the stars will fall from heaven, and the powers of heaven will be shaken.
30 Then the sign of the Son of Man will appear in heaven, and then all the tribes of the earth will mourn, and they will see ‘the Son of Man coming on the clouds of heaven’ with power and great glory.
31 And he will send out his angels with a loud trumpet call, and they will gather his elect from the four winds, from one end of heaven to the other.
32 “From the fig tree learn its lesson: as soon as its branch becomes tender and puts forth its leaves, you know that summer is near.
33 So also, when you see all these things, you know that he is near, at the very gates.
34 Truly I tell you, this generation will not pass away until all these things have taken place.

Christians offer numerous explanations for this prophecy:

The prophecy was conditional on the people of Israel 'repenting' and accepting Jesus, and was delayed because this did not occur
"This generation" does not refer to a generation of people, but to a specific 'race' of people
"This generation" does not refer to the generation of Jesus's contemporaries, but to a later group
The prophecy did actually come true in the 1st Century when Jerusalem was destroyed (the 'Preterist' position')

Question
LDS Christians offer several resolutions for Joseph Smith's apparent prophetic mistake, and these explanations seem to have significant overlap with Christian explanations of Matthew 24. How do non-LDS Christians who reject D&C 84 as a false prophecy defend using the same explanations that Mormons do?

Joseph Smith isn’t considered a false prophet because of this specific prophecy - which most non-LDS probably aren’t aware of in the first place. Of course, any false prophecy makes a false prophet. Joseph Smith has a number of things against him - like a secret Golden Tablet that only he had access to, a whole mythology about the people of the Americas after Christ that has no archeological evidence to back it up, many of those at the start of the Book of Mormon that served to testify to it’s authenticity subsequently recanted, the theology of the Book of Mormon conflicts with the NT, etc.

@AviAvraham, the early temple you mentioned that was built was in Kirtland, Ohio – not Kirkland, Washington. The city names are easy to get mixed up. :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirtland_Temple

Why would you think Joseph Smith's explanation of Matthew 24 would be original? People have been perplexed and finding interpretations for that passage for a millennium before Smith.

You have a two questions loaded together that makes it impossible for me to truly answer. Could you edit this so it is answerable?`Do you want info on how non LDS denominations respond to a specific thing or do you want information about the passage in matthew 24 about the end of the world?

@RyanPierceWilliams there was no recanting, some of the witnesses left the LDS faith, but none recanted their witness/testimony of the Book of Mormon (at least to my knowledge)

related questions: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/44860/22319, https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/7069/22319, https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/26772/22319

@Wyrsa the former, I edited the question for focus

@depperm They may not have made a public recantation, however their actions and the actions of the LDS church tell us everything we need to know. The LDS church excommunicated many of these witnesses for being dissenters and for power struggles with Joseph Smith. By doing so, the LDS church undermined any merit to their testimony; for their acts of rebellion, though internal rather than a public declaration, serve as a recantation. Furthermore, the entire idea of relying upon the testimony of men to establish the merits of a prophet / scripture is contrary to the Word of God (John 5:31-47).

@curiousdannii I didn’t bring up Joseph Smith’s explanation of Matthew 24 anywhere, unsure what that’s in reference to

@RyanPierceWilliams so the LDS church excommunicated witnesses, but still keeps them in the BoM, shouldn't that tell you something. Wouldn't a dissenter, excommunicated person explicitly recant witness if untrue? many were asked by others to recant but none did. I don't fully accept your implication of those verses, in that testimony of men doesn't but testimony of men with the spirit would

@depperm the fact that they rely upon human testimony to establish the truth of the Book of Mormon and Joseph Smith as a prophet demonstrates an irreconcilable difference between the Bible + the true Prophets of God and Joseph Smith. God doesn’t rely upon human testimony to establish himself - but provides testimony through his Word and Deeds. The fact that the LDS had to excommunicate many of these witnesses is icing on the cake that proves the foolishness of relying upon human testimony for establishing the merits of God’s Word and deeds.

@RyanPierceWilliams what exactly do you think the bible is a compilation of? men establishing the word of God. Judas left the apostles to sell Jesus...does that mean Jesus isn't the Christ because he was betrayed? (or Peter who denied him) It doesn't matter that Judas left or Peter denied him, when we have testimony of men who followed him Matt 16:16-18, see also https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/41702/18064

@depperm The scriptures include many genres, but in general it is a recording of God's activity through his prophets and the his people. It also includes lots of prophecy, proverbs, songs, etc. Recording these things allows us to share the Word of God - but simply transcribing it does not in of itself serve to establish it as the word of God. There are any number of purported scriptures that didn't make either the Jewish or Christian cannons. Additionally, the question of the authenticity of a given scripture is different from the authenticity of a prophet, though related.

@depperm What establishes the Bible as the Word of God or any of the prophets therein as true prophets is God himself - through his Word and Deeds working together to testify of its truth. Recording a prophecy does not thereby prove it is authentic - nor does  recording a purpoted miracle by itself establish it as the authentic Word of God. It is when both come together (2 witnesses) that truth is established. First God's prophets foretell what God is going to do and then he brings it to pass. Yet there is no biblical precedent for Joseph Smith or his uncovering a secret history.

@depperm As for Judas and the rest of the disciples - Jesus didn't rely upon their testimony to establish who he was. His testimony was the Word and Deeds of God alone. Again, see John 5:31-47

@RyanPierceWilliams if you read my question, you'll see I asked How do non-LDS Christians who reject D&C 84 as a false prophecy defend using the same explanations that Mormons do

I don't really see this as a prophecy question. There are several reasons/arguments for overlap:

correlation fallacy: arguments can be correlated without the same cause

many bible verses have several interpretations by various denominations/people, many of them similar to others, this does not mean they believe similar things


Fallacy of affirming the conclusion/consequent (keep in mind: fallacy fallacy-just because a fallacy has been made does not mean the claim made is false)

Jesus made an 'unfulfilled' prophesy, there are arguments/interpretations for this prophesy, Jesus is a prophet; Joseph Smith made an 'unfulfilled' prophesy, there are arguments/interpretations for the prophesy, Joseph must be a prophet too


law of consistent reasoning not being applied

non-LDS Christians believe Jesus is a prophet in regardless of Matt 24, not because of it, non-LDS Christians do not believe Joseph Smith is a prophet regardless of D&C 84 (probably not a large reason for believing Joseph isn't a prophet, not 100% certain but this hasn't come up often)


cherry picking fallacy

select arguments have been picked to draw similarities between interpretation of these verses, but this ignores any interpretation that can't/isn't shared with the other.
see How can the "Son of Man" passages of Matthew 24 be interpreted as a fulfilled prophecy? for specific interpretation of Matthew 24 that doesn't apply to D&C 84
see D&C Institute manual for further clarification on D&C 84 that don't apply to Matthew 24


Several years later, after the Saints had established themselves in Nauvoo, Illinois, the Lord declared that they were excused from the commandment to build the city of New Jerusalem and the temple (see D&C 124:49–51). Nevertheless, the Lord’s promises remain that Zion will one day be redeemed and the New Jerusalem will be built (see D&C 100:13; 105:9; 136:18).



No defense is needed to use similar (the same) explanations, especially when not all of the explanations/arguments match.

Thanks for the thoughtful answer. but this ignores any interpretation that can't/isn't shared with the other. - some examples of apologetics for Matthew 24 that cannot be used for D&C 84 would help me understand your answer

@AviAvraham I don't think I'm going to investigate more examples, I just don't think there happen to be only 4 arguments for each verse that happen to sound similar (ie you have cherry picked 4 arguments for each that sound similar to each other) Even the provided examples sound similar but an age or dispensation is different than a specific race of people. I provided multiple reasons anyone could argue one but not the other

Well usually an accusation of cherry picking would include which critical data are being ignored

non-LDS Christians do not believe Joseph Smith is a prophet regardless of D&C 84 non-LDS Christians who accuse Joseph Smith of making false prophecies use D&C84 as well as other writings and sayings to make that point, but so as to not be accused of “lacking focus” I limited the question to a single Mormon prophecy. I can happily add the others

@AviAvraham I've referenced SO question that address Matt 24, that doesn't address D&C 84, and a lds manual that doesn't apply to Matt 24

@AviAvraham it is one argument, but as you pointed out it has arguments/interpretations that can be made. Feel free to make other another question (I don't think adding other prophesies to this question would be in scope)

As a non-LDS person, I maintain that I have no need to "defend" the interpretation of "that generation" Jesus made prophecies about, if the LDS use the same interpretation for Joseph Smith's 'generation prophecy'. There are logical principles at work here, irrespective of anything else. Where LDS interpretations are, in principle, the same that my non-LDS Christian group uses for interpreting a prophetic generation, there would be no issue. This can be demonstrated by using another group's stance on Jesus' generation prophecy.
This other group claimed that a generation should be taken literally as about 36 years. (As stated in writing by their first President.) That led them to foretell a future date for when that generation would see Armageddon. The date came and went, without Armageddon, so they had to then re-interpret what "a generation" meant. They began to spin it out, claiming that it wasn't the generation prior to the date they gave; it must mean the generation alive at the time of that date, and old enough to understand matters. More decades went by so they said it was anyone born on that date that would remain alive, to see Armageddon. But (by then) they added that a generation wasn't 36 years, it was the biblical "three-score and ten" (with another ten, as Psalm 90:10 indicates). Ah, but even that stretched-out interpretation eventually snapped, so the next step was to shove the old date out into the wings, effectively dropped for the purpose of interpreting "that generation". Interesting, isn't it?
Why I detail this is to show that each group will interpret "that generation" as they see fit, either for Jesus' prophecy, or for Joseph Smith's. I have no interest in Joseph Smith's prophecy as I see no link to what Jesus said about his return to usher in the Day of Resurrection and Judgment. The only interest I have in any religious group interpreting a particular generation as involved in any outworking of prophecy, is whether their interpretation proves to be true, or false. An indication that an interpretation may be false is when its proponents start moving their prophetic goalposts to make them so wide as to 'allow' their prophet's claims to still be taken seriously.
Jesus was not a false prophet with regard to the generation he warned which would see the destruction of Jerusalem's temple; that happened nearly 40 years later, in A.D. 70, so, "that generation" knew he had prophesied correctly. I recently gave proof of that in a Hermeneutics question - https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/99180/mark-1330-did-jesus-words-fail-or-prove-to-be-untrue/99183#99183
As for whichever generation is alive to see the greater tribulation, and greater (global) destruction of Christ's enemies, that will be identified by the spectacular signs and plagues on earth in Christ's end-time Revelation prophecies. And, regarding Jerusalem, it is clearly stated there that it is heavenly Jerusalem, not any earthly Jerusalem: another reason why Joseph Smith's claims about a literal temple in America is of no interest to me. The LDS will interpret that prophecy as they see fit to avoid their prophet being labelled a false prophet. Time will tell if their principles of interpretation agreed with those that my group uses for Christ's still future prophecies. If they agree, fine. If they disagree, I won't be surprised.
There is nothing for me to defend, as my answer in the link above will prove. (By the way, I am NOT a Preterist. You seem to misunderstand what that means, for the prophecies in Revelation were still to happen, when given near the end of the 1st century, many of them even now being seen in the build-up to Christ's still future return. But I will not go into that here, as that is another question.)

Half of the explanations for Jesus' prophesy need no justification because fully half of the same explanations used by LDS are invalidated by the very text of the prophesy itself.
In OP two of the four example arguments used for explanation of each of the two prophesies in question have to do with the meaning of the phrase 'this generation'.  In the case of Matthew 24 the term remains difficult to definitively ascertain.  In the case of D&C 84 the definition of the phrase is given.
Doctrines and Covenants 84:3 says the temple will be dedicated by the hand of Joseph Smith. I think that serves to define what is meant by 'this generation' in 84:5 unless there's an LDS belief that Smith is coming back from the dead to dedicate a temple.
Therefore, the multiple possible meanings of the phrase 'this generation' remains viable for Jesus' prophesy whereas for Smith's prophesy they do not because it is self defined to mean the generation within which Smith lived.

how does this answer the question(s)?

@depperm It brings clarity to what is meant when Smith says "this generation" won't pass away until.... There is no comparable clarity in Matthew when Jesus uses the same phrase.

But Mike that wasn't the question? :/

@Wyrsa Do these edits help?

The Question was: "How do non-LDS Christians who reject D&C 84 as a false prophecy defend using the same explanations that Mormons do?" and your answer is "An example of how a Non-LDS person would defend the prophecies" The accuracy of the two example prophecies is not the issue this time. IMHO. :) And yes, those edits really do make it more clear to read.

@Wyrsa Non-LDS Christians may use the same "this is what 'this generation' may actually mean" explanations without hypocrisy because when used by LDS (in this specific example) it is an invalid usage since 'this generation' is defined within their prophesy.

On the contrary, in D&C 84:3 the direct object of "dedicated" is the city, not the temple itself. Verse 3 also presupposes dedication in stages by multiple people. The verse is certainly relevant to a  discussion of the New Jerusalem, but verse 3 does not say what this answer claims it says.

@HoldToTheRod Verse 3 "Which city shall be built, beginning at the temple lot" and verse 4 "New Jerusalem shall be built by the gathering of the saints, beginning at this place, even the place of the temple".  How can it be claimed that the dedication refers to the city and not the temple when the temple is the beginning of the city?  Additionally, the dedication of the "city" (which clearly begins with the temple) may be in stages but it is by Joseph Smith and others.  If Joseph Smith didn't do it, it must be too late now unless he's coming back.

@MikeBorden you are conflating building and dedicating. Multiple locations in the region, including the temple lot, were dedicated by Joseph Smith and others.

@MikeBorden if, for sake of simple example, there were 10 sites in the area which were to be dedicated, and Joseph Smith dedicated 4, Sidney Rigdon dedicated 3, and 3 other individuals were to dedicate 1 each, it would be correct to say that the area was dedicated by Joseph Smith and others. It is not uncommon for a site to be dedicated before a building is constructed, and another dedication of the completed structure to be held later.

Well, You've neglected a completely different definition of "Generation", you've pointed out that people "explain it as" something else. So that's not really intellectually reasonable here.
(Standard blurb about how I'm eastern Orthodox here)

"Genea" doesn't mean "Generation" as we use it in modern english, so the point about it being "Race, stock, family, offspring, a nation, etc" are perfectly valid points. Independent of if you believe in the LDS position or not.

Blessed Theophylact in his commentary on the passage interprets the parable of the budding fig tree to refer to the Second Coming. This is how he interprets the verse (Luke 21:32):
He says generation, meaning, not only those who lived at the time, but the generation of all believers who have alike have been baptized and reborn in Christ. Scripture uses generation to refer to those who are alike in some way; for example, This is the generation of them that seek the Lord. (Ps. 23:6).
Thus, Blessed Theophylact interprets “this generation” to mean the Church. This is identical to St. John Chrysostom’s interpretation of the corresponding verse in Matthew (Matt. 24:34).
So here we are, the "Church" as the body of all believers will not pass away until all these things come to pass. Would be the way the church interprets it, based on similar understandings of church fathers.

Looking at the LDS prophecy... it is eisegesis "reading what he wanted to see" interpretation. But that is not what you asked about, you asked how can non-LDS defend the passage with similar arguments.
I disagree with all the arguments that are trying to define the end times in some sense, because we are not going to know, we are not going to suddenly "figure it out" all of that is a false starting point that can only lead to a bad result.
The end times will arrive like a thief in the night. But at least the Church will still be there. Personally the more concerning issue in that whole prophecy is what Christ had to say about how love will become cold... I look around and see that people still donate to charity, even the multitude of other sects still are loving and attempt to help those in need.
While we do live in the "end times", that does not mean the end of the world is nigh, but it also does not mean we can "live as if it is not about to happen at any moment".

There is no problem with using similar defenses, the real issue here is that the interpretation of the scripture was eisegesis and thus was flawed from the onset.
The defenses of the prophecy are completely legit methods. Our reasoning is not flawed neither are those of heretics and false prophets... the problem is that the theology does not point to God, but to something else.
This means that the fundamental original perspective of Joseph was flawed. (Not your question in some way)
The defenses for a prophecy are valid, the words are right, the theology is pointed in different directions. Theology should point to God, predicting the end times does not.

the real issue here is that the initial premise was flawed - sorry, I've read this answer a few times and can't find which premise in my question is flawed. Your point about γενεά is one of 4 shared explanations for Joseph Smith/Jesus's prophecies, but that's not the premise of my question. Just a single argument

@AviAvraham I did not say that your premise was flawed. Let me edit that to be more clear.
